# How do i check an expression like this (9+5)*(8/2) using .Net Regular Expression? In other words the only valid characters are [0-9] and ()+-*/

Tags: c#, regex

I know how to check for number 0-9. However, every time i add `()+-*/` , it doesn't work. I have tried the following combinations
`^[0-9|(|)|-|+|*|/]$ and ^[0-9][()-+*/]$`

Comment: This kind of problem isn't well suited for regex. You should be looking at a parser instead.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, How would i go about this using parser ? Can you please elaborate more on your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Read about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and use such in a proper way.

Your allowed characters are `[()0-9/*+-]` where it's important to escape `-` or put it at the start/end of the class for not indicating a range. Attach [a quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` for one or more or `*` for any amount and [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) it like you did, so the pattern becomes something like this.

```
^[()0-9/*+-]+$
```

[See demo at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B()0-9%2F*%2B-%5D%2B%24&i=(9%2B5)*(8%2F2))

Comment: Thank you exactly what i needed.